# There is an higher probability to win with 3 dices versus 2 or with 4 dices versus 3?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

In [Dice wars](http://www.gamedesign.jp/flash/dice/dice.html), you gain a territory rolling the dices you have in an adiacent territory (almost like [Risk game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_%28game%29)).

If I have more options to choose, there are more chances to win with 3 dices versus 2 or with 4 dices versus 3?

So, generalizing, if I have one dice more than the opponent, it make difference the number of other dices?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Is this a question about how to use the software *Mathematica*?  If not, then you're at the wrong site.  It seems like a question about mathematics (probability).

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I'll keep this question here only for wxffles' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean this question for [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) rather than [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), but you can use Mathematica to brute force the probabilities:

```
d2 = Flatten@Outer[Plus, Range@6, Range@6];
d3 = Flatten@Outer[Plus, Range@6, Range@6, Range@6];
d4 = Flatten@Outer[Plus, Range@6, Range@6, Range@6, Range@6];
```

Chance of winning with 3 dice versus 2 dice:

```
Total@#/Length@# &@Flatten@Outer[Boole@Greater@## &, d3, d2] // N
```

> `0.778549`

Chance of winning with 4 dice versus 3 dice:

```
Total@#/Length@# &@Flatten@Outer[Boole@Greater@## &, d4, d3] // N
```

> `0.742831`

So you are better off going for *fewer* dice if you can have just one more.  (I also checked for 5 vs 4).

A real mathematician might be along shortly to prove this.  Maybe they could also work out an asymptote.